# Flutter : How to draw a vertical sine wave inside a container?

Tags: flutter, flutter-canvas

How can I draw something like this inside a container in flutter?.
PS I am new to flutter.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: it just looks like a sin curve or it has a defined equation?

Comment: Hi, its just a sine curve, there is no equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, the idea is using multiple `quadraticBezierTo`. Remember that B, C, D should be on the same line to make the joint smooth:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 300,
            height: 700,
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: CustomPaint(painter: FaceOutlinePainter()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FaceOutlinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 8.0;

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(size.width / 2, 0); //Ax, Ay
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height / 8, size.width / 2, size.height / 4); //Bx, By, Cx, Cy
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, 3 * size.height / 8, size.width / 2, size.height / 2); //Dx, Dy, Ex, Ey
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FaceOutlinePainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Is there a way I can make it fit to container length