# How to make custom paint lines edges in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-custompainter

[This is first image which i want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrJQS.jpg)

[This is the second image which i achieved using that code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpzkO.jpg)

**I have to create an animation like line moving from left to right in zigzag motion with round curves .This custom-paint code generates these lines but these are straight zig-zag lines like , i want to make these lines with some round  curve in them  how can i do that

I have to create an animation like line moving from left to right in zigzag motion with round curves .This custom-paint code generates these lines but these are straight zig-zag lines like , i want to make these lines with some round  curve in them  how can i do that
I have to create an animation like line moving from left to right in zigzag motion with round curves .**

```
  class DigitalWavePainter extends CustomPainter {
    final double animationValue;
    final double widthOfCanvas;
    final double heightOfCanvas;   
    DigitalWavePainter(
        this.animationValue, this.widthOfCanvas, this.heightOfCanvas);
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final width = widthOfCanvas;
    final height = heightOfCanvas;   
    final path = Path();   
    final path2=Path();    
    final numSegments = 200; // Increase the number of line segments
    final segmentWidth = width / numSegments;    
    final amplitude = height + 10;
    final upperBoundary = height * 0.01;
    final lowerBoundary = height; // Adjust the lower boundary value    
    final waveProgress = animationValue * 2;
    final waveProgressCircle = animationValue;
    double dotY = 0;
    double dotX = -50;
    path.moveTo(width, (math.sin(0) * amplitude) + height / 2); // Start at the initial point of the wave
    path2.moveTo(-50, (math.sin(0) * amplitude) + height / 2);    
        for (int i = 1; i <= numSegments; i++) {
        final x = i * segmentWidth ;
        final animationTime = (x / width * math.pi) + waveProgress * math.pi;
        final y = (math.sin(animationTime) * amplitude) + height / 12;
        dotY = y;
        if (y < upperBoundary) {
          final newY = upperBoundary;
          dotY = newY;
          dotX = x;            
      path2.lineTo(
         x,newY
          );
        } else if (y > lowerBoundary) {
          final newY = lowerBoundary;
          dotY = newY;
          dotX = x;
           path2.quadraticBezierTo(x - segmentWidth, newY, x, newY);               
          print("lower boundary");
        } else {
          dotX = x;
          dotY = y;
          path2.lineTo(x, y);
        }
      }    
    for (int i = 1; i <= numSegments / 2; i++) {
      final x = width - i * segmentWidth;
      final animationTime = (x / width * math.pi) + waveProgress * math.pi;
      final y = (math.sin(animationTime) * amplitude) + height / 12;
      dotY = (math.sin(animationTime) * amplitude) + height / 12;
      if (y < upperBoundary) {
        final newY = upperBoundary;    
        dotY = newY ;
     path.quadraticBezierTo(x + segmentWidth, newY, x, newY);
      } else if (y > lowerBoundary) {
        final newY = lowerBoundary;   
        dotY = newY;        
         path.quadraticBezierTo(x + segmentWidth, newY, x, newY);
      } else {
        dotY = y;
        path.lineTo(x, y);
      }
    } 
    const dotRadius = 20.0; // Set the radius of the dot    
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeWidth = 16.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round; 
    final circlePaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
  
    final boundaryPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 5.0;   
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path2,paint);
    // Draw the dot as a filled circle at the current position
    canvas.drawCircle(
      Offset(width / 2, dotY + animationValue),
      dotRadius,
      circlePaint,
    );   
    // Draw the boundary circle
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(width / 2, dotY), dotRadius, boundaryPaint);
  }   
    @override
    bool shouldRepaint(DigitalWavePainter oldDelegate) {
      return oldDelegate.animationValue != animationValue;
    }   
  }
```

Comment: You can use this and adapt it to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70619693/flutter-how-to-draw-a-vertical-sine-wave-inside-a-container

Comment: Can you share image of expected result and what you have achieved so far?

Comment: @AkshayGupta i have edit the post with image links both which i want and which i achieved , please check and give me solution.

Answer (score 0):

> digitalVavePainter.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stackoverflow_demo/screens/zig_zag_demo.dart';

class DigitalVavePainter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<DigitalVavePainter> createState() => _DigitalVavePainterState();
}

class _DigitalVavePainterState extends State<DigitalVavePainter> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff171e26),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Text(
                  "Sleep",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 170),
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Text(
                  "ExHale",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
          ),
          Center(
            child: CustomPaint(
              size: Size(double.infinity, screenHeight * 1),
              painter: ZigZagPainter(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> create class file ZigZagPainter.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ZigZagPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Define the points for the cubic Bézier curve
    double startPointX = size.width * 0.00;
    double startPointY = size.height * 0.35;
    double endPointX = size.width * 1;
    double endPointY = size.height * 0.5;

    Offset startPoint = Offset(startPointX, startPointY);
    Offset endPoint = Offset(endPointX, endPointY);
    Offset controlPoint1 = Offset(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.3);
    Offset controlPoint2 = Offset(size.width * 0.8, size.height * 0.7);

    // Create the path for the cubic Bézier curve
    var path = Path()
      ..moveTo(startPoint.dx, startPoint.dy)
      ..cubicTo(
        controlPoint1.dx,
        controlPoint1.dy,
        controlPoint2.dx,
        controlPoint2.dy,
        endPoint.dx,
        endPoint.dy,
      );

    // Create a paint object and set its properties
    var paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 4.0;

    // Draw the cubic Bézier curve on the canvas
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    // Calculate the position and tangent at t = 0.5 (middle of the curve)
    var metrics = path.computeMetrics();
    var middleMetric = metrics.elementAt(0);
    var middlePosition =
        middleMetric.getTangentForOffset(middleMetric.length / 2)!.position;

    // Draw a circle at the middle position
    var circlePaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    canvas.drawCircle(middlePosition, 10, circlePaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: does the line moving from left to right?

Comment: yes you can move line with start point to end point

Comment: actually this is animation , means the line is moving from left to right continously and the circle also move verticaly up and down according to the line.Can you share me your any gmail account so i can send you the video.

Comment: darshank.stacksum@gmail.com